# docker build does not download files

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2

Am trying to run a Dockerbuild from within an EC2 Instance. The curl command to download the zip file works in the EC2 Instance itself. But when I run:

```
docker build . -t my-custom-kibana:1
```

I get the following error. Any ideas why the docker build isn't able to download but a normal curl in the EC2 works fine? *Interestingly, the first line works absolutely fine. (FROM artifactory.cloud.myorg.com/kibana:6.4.2)*

> Plugin installation was unsuccessful due to error "Client request
>   error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND artifactory.cloud.myorg.com
>   artifactory.cloud.myorg.com:443" The command '/bin/sh -c kibana-plugin
>   install https://artifactory.cloud.myorg.com:443/my-plugin.zip'
>   returned a non-zero code: 70

This is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM artifactory.cloud.myorg.com/kibana:6.4.2
RUN kibana-plugin install https://artifactory.cloud.myorg.com:443/my-plugin.zip

EXPOSE 5601

CMD ["/usr/local/bin/kibana-docker"]
```

Comment: Wierd - where did the other Posts go? @SiHa yes I did try without the 443. Like i said, the CURL with those arguments works on the EC2 but not within docker build (to test)

Comment: FYI the ERROR I get is Error: `Client request error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND artifactory.cloud.myorg.com artifactory.cloud.myorg.com:443
Plugin installation was unsuccessful due to error "Client request error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND artifactory.cloud.myorg.com artifactory.cloud.myorg.com:443"`

Comment: The error is `ENOTFOUND artifactory.cloud.myorg.com artifactory.cloud.myorg.com:443`, note the duplication of the repository. Is it possible that the `kibana-plugin` is pre-configured in the container to use `artifactory.cloud.myorg.com`, so you actually just need `RUN kibana-plugin install my-plugin.zip`?

Comment: No it needs to be a full URI or kibana-plugin indirectly tries to go out to artifacts.elastic.co/  repository which is outside our corporate firewall and is disallowed